# Split pandas column and create new columns that count the split values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a goofy data where one column contains multiple values slammed together with a comma:

```py
In [62]: df = pd.DataFrame({'U': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'V': ['a,b,a,c,d', 'a,b,c', 'd,e']})                                     

In [63]: df                                                                                                                      
Out[63]: 
     U          V
0  foo  a,b,a,c,d
1  bar      a,b,c
2  baz        d,e
```

Now I want to split column `V`, drop it, and add columns `a` through `e`.  Columns `a` through `e` should contains the count of the occurrences of that letter in that row:

```
In [62]: df = pd.DataFrame({'U': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'V': ['a,b,a,c,d', 'a,b,c', 'd,e']})                                     

In [63]: df                                                                                                                      
Out[63]: 
     U  a  b  c  d  e
0  foo  2  1  1  1  0
1  bar  1  1  1  0  0
2  baz  0  0  0  1  1
```

Maybe some combination of `df['V'].str.split(',')` and `pandas.get_dummies` but I can't quite work it out.

Edit: apparently I have to justify why my question is not a duplicate. I think why is intuitively obvious to the most casual observer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is `str.get_dummies`

```
pd.concat([df,df.pop('V').str.split(',',expand=True).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)],1)
Out[602]: 
     U  a  b  c  d  e
0  foo  2  1  1  1  0
1  bar  1  1  1  0  0
2  baz  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Once again this answer shows your deep knowledge of pandas. Great answer! Cant upvote this enough

Comment: You can add a `.drop("V",1)` to match the desired output exactly.

Comment: @pault using pop :-)

Comment: All in one line. Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `pandas.Series.str.count`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'U': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'V': ['a,b,a,c,d', 'a,b,c', 'd,e']})

columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
# If unknown or large set of columns, then replace above with:
# columns = sorted(set(df['V'].str.split(',').sum()))

for column in columns:
    df[column] = df['V'].str.count(column)

print(df)
#      U          V  a  b  c  d  e
# 0  foo  a,b,a,c,d  2  1  1  1  0
# 1  bar      a,b,c  1  1  1  0  0
# 2  baz        d,e  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Only works if you know the possible values in advance

Comment: @pault - you are right. If column values are unknown, then you could replace the list in the for loop with the result of something like `sorted(set(df['V'].str.split(',').sum()))` instead.

Comment: I do happen to know all possible values, but that seems tedious. The version in the comments is nice, though!